# How can I log in to YouTube using Perl?

Tags: perl, screen-scraping, youtube

I am trying to write a Perl script to connect to me YouTube account but it doesnt seem to work. Basically I just want to connect to my account but apparently it is not working. I don't even have an idea on how I could debug this! Maybe it is something related to https protocol?

Please enlighten me! Thanks in advance.

```
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use strict;

my $login="test";
my $pass = "test";
my $res = "";
my $ua = "";

# Create user agent, make it look like FireFox and store cookies
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20051213 Firefox/1.0.7");
$ua->cookie_jar ( {} );

# Request login page 
$res = $ua->request(GET "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=youtube&hl=en_US&passive=true&ltmpl=sso&uilel=3&continue=http%3A//www.youtube.com/signup%3Fhl%3Den_US%26warned%3D%26nomobiletemp%3D1%26next%3D/index");
die("ERROR1: GET http://www.youtube.com/login\n") unless ($res->is_success);


# Now we login with our user/pass
$res = $ua->request(
        POST "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=youtube",
        Referer => "http://www.youtube.com/login",
        Content_Type => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Content => [
                currentform     => "login",
                next            => "/index",
                username        => $login,
                password        => $pass,
                action_login    => "Log+In"
        ]
        );

# YouTube redirects (302) to a new page when login is success
# and returns OK (200) if the login failed.
#die("ERROR: Login Failed\n") unless ($res->is_redirect());


print $res->content;
```

---

what i am doing is learning the web features of perl, so i dont want to use any library except wwwlib or mechanize to get the job done.
how can i just connect to my account using a perl script? this is my objective for now
hope someone can post a script or correct mine.
thank you guys for you help.
i am testing Webscarab now..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What data are you trying to grab?   Why not just using an existing implementation like [`WebService::YouTube`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WebService::YouTube)

Some comments on your code:    I always avoided the shortcut `$ua->request(GET/POST)` method since I always ended up needing more flexibility that only the use of [`HTTP::Request`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Request) and [`HTTP::Response`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Response) allowed.   I always felt the code was cleaner that way too.

Why is your code not working?  Who knows.
Make sure your cookiejar is adding your cookies to the outgoing [`HTTP::Request`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP::Request). I'd suggest dumping all your headers when you do it in a browser and compare with the headers and data that [`libwww`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) is sending.  There may be some additional fields that they are checking for that vary for every hit.  They may be checking for your `UserAgent` string.    If you are just looking to learn [`libwww`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/) I'd suggest using a different site as a target as I'm sure YouTube has all sort of anti-scripting hardening.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using [YouTube's stable documented API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html)?

Use an HTTP proxy such as [WebScarab](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) to watch the data flow.

Trey's suggestion to use somebody else's CPAN package for the mechanics is a good idea too.

Answer (score 1):

Right right by and large, what you want to do is define a cookiejar for most of these websites that have a redirection login. This is what the package has done. Also the package tunes a lot of the lookups and scrapes based on the youtube spec.

Ajax content for example will be rough since its not there when your scraping

You just picked a somewhat rough page to start out with.

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually working on this issue myself. Before, I would suggest read over this the [API guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Direct_uploading) from Google as a good starting reference. If I'm reading it correctly, one begins with passing user credentials through a REST interface to get a Authentication Token. To handle that, I'm using the following:

```
sub getToken {
  my %parms = @_;
  my $response    = LWP::UserAgent->new->post(
                   'https://www.google.com/youtube/accounts/ClientLogin',
                   [
                         Email   => $parms{'username'},
                         Passwd  => $parms{'password'},
                         service => "youtube",
                         source  => "<<Your Value Here>>",                            
                   ]
    );


    my $content = $response->content;


    my ($auth) = $content =~ /^Auth=(.*)YouTubeUser(.*)$/msg
           or die "Unable to authenticate?\n";
    my ($user) = $content =~ /YouTubeUser=(.*)$/msg
            or die "Could not extract user name from response string. ";

    return ($auth, $user);
}
```

And I call that from the main part of my program as such:

```
## Get $AuthToken
my ($AuthToken, $GoogleUserName) = getToken((
                          username => $email, password => $password
                          ));
```

Once I have these two things -- $AuthToken and $GoogleUserName, I'm still testing the LWP Post. I'm still writing this unit:

```
sub test {

my %parms = @_;

## Copy file contents. Use, foy's three param open method. 
my $fileSize = -s $parms{'File'};
open(VideoFile, '<', "$parms{'File'}") or die "Can't open $parms{'File'}.";
binmode VideoFile;
read(VideoFile, my $fileContents, $fileSize) or die "Can't read $parms{'File'}";
close VideoFile;




my $r = LWP::UserAgent->new->post(
    "http://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$parms{'user'}/uploads",
    [
        Host              => "uploads.gdata.youtube.com",
        'Authorization'     => "AuthSub token=\"$parms{'auth'}\"",
        'GData-Version'     => "2",
        'X-GData-Key'       => "key=$YouTubeDeveloperKey",
        'Slug'              => "$parms{'File'}",
        'Content-Type'      => "multipart/related; boundary=\"<boundary_string>\"",
        'Content-Length'    => "<content_length>",
        'video_content_type'=> "video/wmv",
        'Connection'        => "close",
        'Content'           => $fileContents
    ]

);


print Dumper(\$r->content)
}
```

And that is called as

```
&test((auth=>$Auth, user=>$user, File=>'test.wmv'));
```